# Capybara testing javascript failure to refresh .count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara

Using Capybara testing javascript alert in rspec. Why

```
expect{
  click_link "Cancel my account"
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
}.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
```

fails. Yet

```
puts User.count
expect{
  click_link "Cancel my account"
  page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.accept
  puts User.count
}.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
```

didn't? How do I fix the test? There is no `reload` function for `User`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using a javascript spec, the browser/JS is running in a different process from your test, and Capybara doesn't know to wait until the browser request completes before continuing, since you haven't issued any Capybara command after accepting the alert. I'm guessing the `puts` adds just enough of a time delay for the actual database to change. If you want to wait for Capybara to return until the next page starts to get loaded (and thus the database has been updated), you can do something like this at the end of the block:

```
page.find('head').
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. In the top case, the user is deleted, why User class is not changed? Is there caching somewhere in ActiveRecord that's causing this? Still confused.

Comment: Sorry, I actually misread your original post. Since you're using a javascript spec, the browser/JS is happening in a different process from your test, and it doesn't know to wait until the browser request completes before continuing. I'm guessing the `puts` adds just enough of a time delay for the actual database to change. If you want to wait  for Capybara to return until the next page starts to get loaded (and thus the database has been updated), you can do something like this at the end of the block: `page.find('head')`.

Comment: That makes sense. And the test indeed passes without the puts. Thank you very much!